# fengyuanchen cropper + caman in Meteor

Tags: meteor, crop

I have a problem using both cropper and caman together. 
I copied the code provided by fengyanchen, and modified it a bit for Meteor. The Caman works, but the cropper doesn't initiate.

Code:
http://codepen.io/chenfengyuan/pen/wMrVQY

HTML

```
<template name="Test">
{{ > index   }}
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Use Cropper with CamanJS</h1>
    <p id="upload">
        <input id="file" type="file">
    </p>
    <p id="handle" style="display:none">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="brightness">Brightness</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="contrast">Contrast</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <canvas id="canvas" style="max-width:100%;"></canvas>
    </p>
</div>
```

My events handler:

...(functions copied as provided in link)

```
Template.Test.events({
'change #file':function(event,template){

    if (URL) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var file;

        if (files && files.length) {
            file = files[0];

            if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
                startCaman(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            } else {
                window.alert('Please choose an image file.');
            }
        }

    } else {
        $file.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I did the following:

- giving the canvas a width & height
- removing var $canvas at the topmost level and replacing it with the real canvas selector everywhere